# MonetDB pystethoscope with Python2?

Tags: python-2.6, monetdb

Does the new MonetDB profiler [pystethoscope](https://twitter.com/MonetDB/status/1272514197407105024) also work with Python 2.6 and up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pystethoscope is only compatible with Python versions 3.5 or later.